# Angular 6 child route's lifecycle not triggered when parent has an assigned component

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, angular-routing

I'm using Angular 6 auxiliary routes for bootstrap modals but I have encountered a problem where the child route's components lifecycle hooks aren't called if the parent route has a component assigned to it. I'm using the lifecycle hooks to trigger the modal as soon as the component has been loaded. My goal is that the "myMenuComponent" should be visible in the background while the modal is active.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
$('#modal').modal('toggle')
}
```

The following routing works and triggers the lifecycle hook as intended but doesn't give me the menu I want to see in the background:

```
{
path: 'mypath',
children: [
  {
    path: 'modal',
    component: myModalComponent,
    outlet: 'modalOutlet'
  }
]
}
```

The following route doesn't trigger any lifecycle hooks:

```
{
path: 'mypath',
component: myMenuComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: 'modal',
    component: myModalComponent,
    outlet: 'modalOutlet'
  }
]
}
```

Comment: Documentation says that `ngAfterViewInit` gets invoked only once. Reference - https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit#methods

Comment: In this case it's never invoked.

Comment: Alright, just to clarify, can you confirm you have implemented the `AfterViewInit interface` in the component to use `ngAfterViewInit` method? Share the code if possible